# How can I access the servlet application context from Struts 2 tags?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

How can I access jsp tags in struts ?
for eg:

```
<s:select name="country" list="<%=countryList%>"  headerKey="0" headerValue="Country"
                  label="Select your country" required="true"/>
```

Exception:

> Messages:  /jsp/index.jsp(35,2) According to TLD or attribute
>   directive in tag file, attribute list does not accept any expressions.
>   countryList is a ArrayList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the exception is clearly indicating the cause as the S2 tag will not allow this expression inside it.
More over Tag require a List/ArrayList or any collection list as a source of Data and build in ONGL mechanism will do the rest of work for you.

You have a clean way to achieve this create a property in your action class with name `countryList` that should have data type as List/Map and provide a getter and setter for this property.Fill the List with the required data in your action class.

### Action Class

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport{

  private List<String> countryList;
  // getter and setter for countryList

  public String execute() throws Exception{
   countryList=new ArrayList<String>();
   // Add values to list
   return SUCCESS;
 }
}
```

Now in your JSP all you need to do following

```
<s:select name="country" list="countryList"  headerKey="0" headerValue="Country"
                  label="Select your country" required="true"/>
```

So when OGNL will find this `list="countryList"` as a data source it will look for a method named getCountryList() in your action class and will use the data to fill the select tag.

Hope this will give u clear idea how this works. For details refer the official document

[select tag](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/select.html)

Comment: yes Umesh thats the ideal way but I am getting the list value from the context and i am taking it directly in my jsp and storing it as an ArrayList.

Comment: By context, do you mean application context? Struts 2 exposes almost everything, and certainly this, you could want via OGNL access from S2 tags.  See this page for info:  http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/ognl.html

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use a java scriptlet for the list.

You have to use an OGNL expression.  If your action has a getCountryList method, all you need to do is:

```
<s:select name="country" list="countryList"  headerKey="0" headerValue="Country"
                  label="Select your country" required="true"/>
```

You should search some documentation on how to use OGNL in struts.  It is really powerful.

Comment: I am getting the list value from the context and i am taking it directly in my jsp. Is there a way to use it? i came across this tag : %{#countryList} what is it?

Comment: That is an OGNL expression that will search the struts stack

Comment: is there a way i can isert value in the stack in my JSP itself?

Comment: @lee: you can use push tag to `push` values to value stack other way is to use `set` tag

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi: can i push a jsp variable value into the stack?